# Different p-value between KS test and Wilcoxon test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to know if the values in vector A are greater than the values in vector B.

Here are my two vectors:

```
  A <- c(6.8,3.1,5.8,4.5,3.3,4.7,4.2,4.9)
  B <- c(4.4,2.5,2.8,2.1,6.6,0.0,4.8,2.3)
```

I used both KS test and Wilcoxon test with the following command in R:

```
  ks.test(B,A,alternative = "greater")
  wilcox.test(B,A,alternative = "greater")
```

With the ks.test, I received p-value=0.04394, which means that we rejet $H_0$ and we can conclude that the values in A are greater than B.

With the Wilcoxon test, I received p-value=0.9675, which means that we do not rejet $H_0$.

Is there something wrong here or I did not well understand the principle of these tests?

Comment: Please read the "Details" portion of the help pages for the two tests.  Their interfaces simply are inconsistent, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your immediate issue is resolved (one of an inconsistent interface), the underlying issue about which you asked remains. There's no reason to expect that the two tests will be consistent, since they look at different things.

The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney responds to changes in $P(X>Y)$, while the Kolmogorov-Smirnov responds to more general changes. There's no reason to expect that you couldn't get a p-value near one for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney and one near 0 for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

In particular consider a case where the two sample-distributions are close to symmetric, with the same location, but the spreads are very different; the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney will have a high p-value but the Kolmogorov-Smirnov should have a low one.

I generated 4 data sets before getting one that had similar characteristics to the p-values you quoted (in this case I looked at two tailed tests but you could get the same issue with one-tailed tests)

```
        x      y
1  -0.549  3.511
2  -0.054 -0.788
3   0.578 -3.911
4  -0.070 -0.846
5   0.158  3.358
6  -0.232  2.457
7  -0.117  2.125
8  -0.057  2.185
9  -0.604 -1.686
10  0.002  0.354
11 -0.270  0.042
12  0.166 -1.554
13 -0.611 -3.333
14  0.387  2.609
15  0.844 -2.249
16 -0.431 -1.516
17  0.850  0.443
18  0.852 -0.628
19  0.775 -0.652
20 -0.872 -2.042
21 -0.986 -3.520
22  0.555  3.346
23 -0.002  3.398
24 -0.090  3.029
25  0.169  1.676
```

The p-value for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney was 0.969, that for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov was 0.036

[image: ecdf plot of the two samples - location is almost the same but the first sample had a smaller spread]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still have things that I could not understand. Could you please explain this sentence please? "while the Kolmogorov-Smirnov responds to more general changes". What are general changes here?

Comment: It's designed to pick up any difference in distribution (explicitly, as measured by the largest absolute difference in the distribution function); there's an example of one such kind of difference that the test is sensitive to right in the question. For more information about the two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)